# How do I import an executable JAR into Netbeans (7.0)?

Tags: netbeans, import, executable-jar

All right, for a project I'm working on for school, I have been provided code to start working with. I would like to create a new project in Netbeans to work on the project. One JAR file provided to me is an executable JAR file that starts the GUI form. How can I add this to my project so that when I click "Run Main Project" (and this project is the main project, obviously) the GUI form starts? I'm assuming this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: erm ... if your jar is "executable", it's compiled code. Netbeans is for editing source code.

Comment: Right, but is there a way I could just get it to run when I run my project in Netbeans? I don't need to edit it, it would just be convenient for that to happen. Thanks.

Comment: @brianRoach maybe you didnt see that last time

Comment: the answer is ... you can't. It's not designed to do that. It's an IDE, not a jar launcher.

Comment: Hmm. It seems like there should be a way to just launch the JAR, but I guess not. Too bad. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a library,
1) Open [Menu ->] Tools -> Libraries -> New Library -> on the "Classpath" tab add your *.jar
2) Import it to your project (right click on "Libraries" folder in the "Projects" window and choose your library)
3) Create instance of class of your library

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I couldn't get that to work. I don't think the JAR is a library but I'm not totally sure how to tell. Like I said, when I run it outside of Netbeans it starts the GUI form which doesn't sound like it's a library.